# Camera collision detection

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, collision, raycasting

I'm having trouble with my Camera script. The Camera rotates around the player by using a pivot that's assigned as a child of the camera. This works with 2 arrows (I'm developing this game for mobiles, so they're touch arrows) that allow the camera to rotate left and right.

The problem is when the Camera goes behind a wall or a huge object and can't see anything. I looked for a solution and I see that many developers used the RaycastHit or something similar.

Here's my code, the goal is to get the Camera to go closer to the pivot when near a wall in order to avoid blocking the Camera view. Can anyone help me?

```
public Transform target1;
public Transform pivot;

protected ButtonLeft buttonLeft;
protected ButtonRight buttonRight;

public Vector3 offset;
public bool useOffsetValues;

public float rotateSpeed;  

private void Start()
{
    buttonLeft = FindObjectOfType<ButtonLeft>();
    buttonRight = FindObjectOfType<ButtonRight>();

    if (!useOffsetValues)
    {
        offset = target1.position - transform.position;
    }

    pivot.transform.position = target1.transform.position;

    //pivot.transform.parent = target.transform;

    //USE IF U WANT TO DISAPPEAR THE CURSOR
    //Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;

    //pivot.transform.parent = target.transform;
    pivot.transform.parent = null;

    // usa questa dopo la costruzione del livello1
    //pivot.transform.position = target.transform.position;
}

private void Update()
{
    pivot.transform.position = target1.transform.position;

    if (buttonLeft.Pressed)
    {
        pivot.Rotate(0, -90 * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        Debug.Log("rotate left");
    }

    if (buttonRight.Pressed)
    {
        pivot.Rotate(0, 90 * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        Debug.Log("rotate left");
    }

    Ray ray = new Ray(pivot.transform.position, pivot.transform.position - transform.position);
    RaycastHit hit;

    /*float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotateSpeed;
    float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotateSpeed;
    pivot.Rotate(0, horizontal, 0);
    pivot.Rotate(0, horizontal, 0);
    Use this to make the camera rotate on Mouse Y axes*/
    /*float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * rotateSpeed;
    target.Rotate(vertical, 0, 0); */

    //move camera based on the current rotation of the target and the original offset

    float desiredYAngle = pivot.eulerAngles.y;
    //Use this float to set the x angle of player
    float desiredXAngle = pivot.eulerAngles.x;
    //Use this rotation only if you want to rotate on Y
    //Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, desiredYAngle, 0);
    //Use this if u want to rotate up&down on x axes
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(desiredXAngle, desiredYAngle, 0);
    transform.position = target1.position - (rotation * offset);

    //transform.position = target.position - offset;

    transform.LookAt(target1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Good approach is when you do raycast from pivot to camera, and, if some obstacle found, put camera on a ray, a bit closer to pivot, than hit point. Like this: (pseudocode, not tested):

```
Vector3 origin =  pivot.transform.position;
Vector3 direction = transform.position - pivot.transform.position;

float maxCameraDistance = 10;

Ray ray = new Ray(origin, direction);
RaycastHit hit;
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, maxCameraDistance))
{
    Vector3 offsetFromObstacle = -direction.normalized * 0.1f;
    transform.position = hit.point + offsetFromObstacle;
}
```

Comment: You can add there a lerp, or move camera not directly to hit point, but to the point right above it, keeping some distance between camera and pivot. For example, add this line after setting position in my code:     transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, 5, transform.position.z);     assuming your camera rotates around Y axis, and 5 is your camera height.